# Magento 2 trying to add an category attribute: DOMDocument::loadXML(): Input is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, xml, category-attribute

I'm trying to add an attribute to the categories, but i'm unable to add the attribute to the admin view by adding the ui_component xml document (module/test/view/adminhtml/ui_component/category_form.xml). See the xml document below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
            <fieldset name="general">
                <field name="custom_attribute">
                    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">50</item>
                            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">varchar</item>
                            <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Custom field</item>
                            <item name="default" xsi:type="number">0</item>
                        </item>
                    </argument>
                </field>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
```

I'm getting the folling code (in short)
1 exception(s):

> Exception #0 (Exception): Warning: DOMDocument::loadXML():

Input is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding !

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
Your Data
</form>` Standard Format

Comment: Explain to me, why you send me the standard format. Didn't I use the standard format?

Comment: Do you use Developer  Mode?

Comment: Yes I use developer Mode

Answer (score 1):

You need to change

```
<item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">varchar</item>
```

to

```
<item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
```

Comment: I already tried changing the datatype. No luck!

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it myself. Just cleared all my caches and setup di compile and deployed the static content. After that there was no more xml exception!